# Conditional <router-link> in Vue.js dependant on prop value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hopefully this is a rather simple question / answer, but I can't find much info in the docs.

Is there a way to enable or disable the anchor generated by `<router-link>` dependent on whether a prop is passed in or not?

```
<router-link class="Card__link" :to="{ name: 'Property', params: { id: id }}">
  <h1 class="Card__title">{{ title }}</h1>
  <p class="Card__description">{{ description }}</p>
</router-link>
```

If there's no `id` passed to this component, I'd like to disable any link being generated.

Is there a way to do this without doubling up the content into a `v-if`?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question, I think you'd have to use `v-if` if you want to conditionally render the `router-link` component based on the existence of the `id` prop. Or do you mean you want the `a` tag to render as something else (like `div`)?

Comment: As @thanksd mentioned, you can specify a router-link tag according to `id` value: `:tag="(id || id == 0) ? 'a' : 'div'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes do stuff like this:

```
<component
    :is="hasSubLinks ? 'button' : 'router-link'"
    :to="hasSubLinks ? undefined : href"
    :some-prop="computedValue"
    @click="hasSubLinks ? handleClick() : navigate"
>
    <!-- arbitrary markup -->
</component>

...

computed: {
    computedValue() {
        if (this.hasSubLinks) return 'something';
        if (this.day === 'Friday') return 'tgif';
        return 'its-fine';
    },
},
```

But I basically always wrap router-link, so you can gain control over disabled state, or pre-examine any state or props before rendering the link, with something like this:

```
<template>
    <router-link
        v-slot="{ href, route, navigate, isActive, isExactActive }"
        :to="to"
    >
        <a
            :class="['nav-link-white', {
                'nav-link-white-active': isActive,
                'opacity-50': isDisabled,
            }]"
            :href="isDisabled ? undefined : href"
            @click="handler => handleClick(handler, navigate)"
        >
            <slot></slot>
        </a>

    </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'top-nav-link',

    props: {
        isDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            default: () => false,
        },

        to: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {};
    },

    computed: {},

    methods: {
        handleClick(handler, navigate) {
            if (this.isDisabled) return undefined;
            return navigate(handler);
        },
    },

};
</script>
```

In my app right now, I'm noticing that some combinations of `@click="handler => handleClick(handler, navigate)"` suffer significantly in performance.

For example this changes routes very slow:

```
@click="isDisabled ? undefined : handler => navigate(handler)"
```

But the pattern in my full example code above works and has no performance issue.

In general, ternary operator in `@click` can be very dicey, so if you get issues, don't give up right away, try many different ways to bifurcate on predicates or switch over `<component :is=""` based on state. navigate itself is an ornery one because it requires the implicit first parameter to work.

I haven't tried, but you should be able to use something like `Function.prototype.call()`, `Function.prototype.apply()`, or `Function.prototype.bind()`.

For example, you might be able to do:

```
@click="handler => setupNavigationTarget(handler, navigate)"

...

setupNavigationTarget(handler, cb) {
    if (this.isDisabled) return undefined;
    return this.$root.$emit('some-event', cb.bind(this, handler));
},

...

// another component
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('some-event', (navigate) => {
        if (['Saturday', 'Sunday'].includes(currentDayOfTheWeek)) {
            // halt the navigation event
            return undefined;
        }

        // otherwise continue (and notice how downstream logic
        // no longer has to care about the bound handler object)
        return navigate();
    });
},
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming you want to disable anchor tag as in not clickable and look disabled the option is using CSS. **isActive** should return true by checking prop id.

```
<router-link class="Card__link" v-bind:class="{ disabled: isActive }" :to="{ name: 'Property', params: { id: id }}">
  <h1 class="Card__title">{{ title }}</h1>
  <p class="Card__description">{{ description }}</p>
</router-link>

<style>
 .disabled {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.6;        
 }
<style>
```

If you want to just disable the navigation , you can use a route guard.

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            next(false);
 }
```

Comment: `pointer-events:none;` works like a charm! but then `cursor:not-allowed` property won't work! Is there any hack for this?

Comment: Note that this also disables other clickable elements inside your component, like buttons.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to use it often, consider this:

Create new component

```
<template>
  <router-link
    v-if="!disabled"
    v-bind="$attrs"
  >
    <slot/>
  </router-link>

  <span
    v-else
    v-bind="$attrs"
  >
    <slot/>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'optional-router-link',

  props: {
    params: Object,
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Optional, register globally:

```
Vue.component('optional-router-link', OptionalRouterLink);
```

Use it as follows:

```
<optional-router-link
  :disabled="isDisabled"
  :to="whatever"
>
    My link
</optional-router-link>
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `router-link` renders as an html anchor tag, and anchor tags do not support the `disabled` attribute. However you can add `tag="button"` to `router-link`:

```
<router-link :to="myLink" tag="button" :disabled="isDisabled" >
```

Vue will then render your link as a button, which naturally supports the `disabled` attribute. Problem solved! The downside is that you have to provide additional styling to make it look like a link. However this is the best way to achieve this functionality and does not rely on any `pointer-events` hack.

Comment: This was helpful for me, but didn't solve the problem 100%.  Some other code was enabling the link again.  So, although it appeared disabled, it was still working.  I ended up conditionally breaking the link's `to` attribute to solve the problem.

Comment: The biggest downside is not in styling requirements, but in using button instead of link for navigation. This automatically makes UX much worse as user can't use all standard browser's navigation controls, as they used to. E.g. "Open link in new tab" action doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Good point @RuslanStelmachenko. So if you need "Open link in new tab" functionality then my suggestion is not the way forward. Instead you should just build your own component that wraps `<router-link>` (using `v-if` logic or whatever). But I didn't mention that because it wouldn't have answered the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the following:

```
<router-link class="Card__link" :to="id ? { name: 'Property', params: { id: id }} : {}">
  <h1 class="Card__title">{{ title }}</h1>
  <p class="Card__description">{{ description }}</p>
</router-link>
```

If id is undefined the router won't redirect the page to the link.

Comment: This was helpful to me, because although I used something like `:disabled="isDisabled"` to make a link appear with a "disabled" style, it still responded to clicks as though it were active.  (I think that's because of some classes applied to the link were used by other code in the app, which made the links active again.)  So, also conditionally breaking the `to` attribute ensures the link truly will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different solutions but only one worked for me, maybe because I'm running if from Nuxt? Although theoretically `nuxt-link` should work exactly the same as `router-link`.

Anyway, here is the solution:

```
<template>
    <router-link
        v-slot="{ navigate }"
        custom
        :to="to"
    >
        <button
            role="link"
            @click="onNavigation(navigate, $event)"
        >
            <slot></slot>
        </button>
    </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'componentName',
    props: {
        to: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onNavigation(navigate, event) {
        if (this.to === '#other-action') {
            // do something
        } else {
            navigate(event);
        }
        return false;
    },
};
</script>
```